# Extracting specific lines from a Large file

Tags: python, algorithm, file, apache-spark

I have a large file (5,000,000 lines) of the format:

```
'User ID,Mov ID,Rating,Timestamp'
```

I have another file(200,000 lines) with much lesser no. of records of the form :

```
'User ID, Mov ID'
```

I have to generate a new file such that if (User ID, Mov ID) from the second file matches any of the records in 5,000,000 lines of first file I should not have it in my new file.
In other words The new file consists of unique User ID, Mov ID in the sense it dosen't have any common (User ID, Mov ID) with file2 (200,000 lines)

I am trying this naive approach but it's taking too much time. Is there a faster algo to implement?:

```
from sys import argv
import re
script, filename1, filename2 = argv
#open files
testing_small= open(filename1)
ratings=open(filename2)
##Open file to write thedata
ratings_training=open("ratings_training.csv",'w')

for line_rating in ratings:
    flag=0;testing_small.seek(0)
    for line_test in testing_small:
        matched_line=re.match(line_test.rstrip(),line_rating)
        if matched_line:
            flag=1;break
    if(flag==0):
        ratings_training.write(line_rating)


testing_small.close()
ratings.close()
ratings_training.close()
```

I can use any spark based methods aswell

Comment: Have you tried pandas/numpy?

Comment: Is it a Csv file?

Comment: Yes, No Im not sure how to use numpy

Comment: This could also be solved with a regular database and key constraints I think. E.g. load all data into the same database, let the databse handle the contraints (e.g. user must be unique), then simply dump the table afterwards. No memory concerns and databases are quite fast when it comes to indexing things

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
# df1:
User_ID,Mov_ID,Rating,Timestamp
sam,apple,0.6,2017-03-17 09:04:39
sam,banana,0.7,2017-03-17 09:04:39
tom,apple,0.3,2017-03-17 09:04:39
tom,pear,0.9,2017-03-17 09:04:39

# df2:
User_ID,Mov_ID
sam,apple
sam,pear
tom,apple
```

In pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('./disk_file')
df2 = pd.read_csv('./tmp_file')
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['User_ID', 'Mov_ID'], how='left', indicator=True)
res = res[res['_merge'] == 'left_only']
print(res)
```

Or in spark:

```
cfg = SparkConf().setAppName('MyApp')
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=cfg).getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.read.load(path='file:///home/zht/PycharmProjects/test/disk_file', format='csv', sep=',', header=True)
df2 = spark.read.load(path='file:///home/zht/PycharmProjects/test/tmp_file', format='csv', sep=',', header=True)
res = df1.join(df2, on=[df1['User_ID'] == df2['User_ID'], df1['Mov_ID'] == df2['Mov_ID']], how='left_outer')
res = res.filter(df2['User_ID'].isNotNull())
res.show()
```

Comment: for spark Intellij IDE is saying  'Cannot Resolve join with such Signature` can you point to a reference examples where we are using the `on` and `how` ?

Comment: which version of spark you use

Comment: I am using 2.1.0. Im using scala 2.11.5

Comment: is it Pyspark you are using?

Answer (score 0):

you should hold the smaller file permanently in memory. then you process the big file line by line without holding the whole file.

code not tested:

```
# read the smaller filter file
filter = set()
with open(reffile, "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        user, movie = line.strip().split(",")
        filter.add((user, movie))
# test the large file an write filtered data
with open(outfile, "wt") as f_out:
    with open(bigfile, "rt") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            user, movie, _, _ = line.strip().split(",")
            if (user, movie) not in filter:
                print(",".join((user, movie)), file=f_out)
```